# plug-in waves have different signature in pdb

Tags: gimp

everyone.

Basically i want to automatically add waves effect with different phase shift, but in python-fu browser i found that `plug-in-waves` have different signature - there is no `phase shift`, `period` or `aspect ratio`.

Where i can get the same function as the one used by GIMP2.8?

[image: nag]

Answer (score 0):

Many Gimp functions have been re-implemented using the GEGL library.

It is currently difficult to call the GEGL functions from a Python plugin (but not impossible, see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Scripting-GEGL-operations) for an example).

To preserve compatibility with existing scripts and plugins, a compatibility layer exists, but it mimics the Gimp 2.8 behavior. In the case at hand, `Phase` and `Wavelength` in the PDB are the same concepts as `Phase shift` and `Period` in the UI (you may need to do some computation to match them). The other parameters (Center and Aspect Ratio) are not available in that version.